# The name does not exist in the current context - Controller Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am following a simple tutorial but there seems to be some version issues. When I try to compile the below code in my ProcessController.cs I get the does not exist in the current context error.

ProcessController.cs

```
public ViewResult List() 
        {
            var processList = from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                              select p;

            ViewData.Model = processList.ToList();

            return View();
        }
```

List.cshtml

```
<ul>
    <% foreach(var process in this.Model) { %>

        <li><%= process.ProcessName %></li>

    <% } %>

</ul>
```

Global.asax.cs (inside class)

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Process",                                                  // Route name
                "{Process}/{action}/{id}",                                    // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Process", action = "List", id = "" }    // Parameter defaults
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProcessController.cs

```
public class ProcessController : Controller
{
    // GET: Processes
    public ViewResult List()
    {
        var processList = from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                          select p;

        ViewData["Model"] = processList.ToList();

        return View();
    }
}
```

The view (List.cshtml) is using razor syntax instead of aspx.
Here is how you can implement that feature in Razor syntax

```
@using System.Diagnostics;
<ul>
 @foreach(var process in ViewData["Model"] as IEnumerable<Process>) { 
  <li>@process.ProcessName</li>
 }
</ul>
```

More about razor syntax:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c

You have to add the following using

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

in the list of using statements

Comment: That change leads to the error... foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type because does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: I updated the code above, so is more detailed now. You have to check your framework targeted version as well